# Module build failed (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to make an ecommerce website with React. And it was working perfectly but after I install `redux` and `react-redux`, I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\ProgrammingHero\foodie\client\node_modules\core-js-pure\modules\esnext.global-this.js'
    at ./node_modules/core-js-pure/modules/esnext.global-this.js (global-this.js:6:1)
    at options.factory (startup:7:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (jsonp chunk loading:133:1)
    at fn (jsonp chunk loading:367:1)
    at ./node_modules/core-js-pure/full/global-this.js (global-this.js:2:1)
    at options.factory (startup:7:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (jsonp chunk loading:133:1)
    at fn (jsonp chunk loading:367:1)
    at ./node_modules/core-js-pure/features/global-this.js (global-this.js:1:1)
    at options.factory (startup:7:1)
```

But if I uninstall `redux` and `react-redux` it works perfectly.

Comment: What's your Node.js version?

Comment: @yousoumar My node version is v14.17.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module build failed (from ./node\_modules/html-loader/dist/cjs.js):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60801331/module-build-failed-from-node-modules-html-loader-dist-cjs-js)

Comment: No! that's not my question.

Comment: I see. You are using npm to install the packages, right ?

Comment: yes! `npm install redux react-redux`

Comment: Try this in your terminal : `rm -rf node_modules yarn.lock package-lock.json && npm i && npm start`

Answer (score 6):

Delete your `node_module` folder and then run

```
 npm i
```

It solves the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

I was reinstall my package.json without delating node_modules and it worked:

just write this :

```
npm i
```

Comment: For me it was also necessary to restart the dev server.

Answer (score 0):

- Uninstall the corresponding library that is throwing the error. (In my case it was history library)
- Try to install the matching versions of the required library. (Sometimes the latest version of some library won't work well with the current configs of other libraries.
- Quit the server and re run again

Answer (score -1):

With the same issue, i just quited from vs code and restarted it, followed with npm start, solved.

Answer (score -1):

This error message indicates that there was a problem with the **source-map-loader** module while building your React app. The **source-map-loader** module is used to load and integrate source maps into webpack bundles, and it is typically used in development environments to improve debugging.

You are getting this error because the **source-map-loader** module is not installed: The source-map-loader module is not installed by default in a React app, so you need to install it manually using the `npm install source-map-loader` or yarn add source-map-loader command. Once you've installed the module, you should be able to build your app without encountering this error.